# Problem: div with width:auto only auto expands up to a certain point

Tags: html, css

From what I undestand a div with width "auto" will auto expand until it fills the parent element. In this example I have a line with multiple icons.

When the number of icons is 7 or more, it's no longer displayed on the same line. There's still more space left, and if I specify a width that is big enough to contain the items, it's displayed on one line.

Why does it only auto expand up to a certain point, when there's still enough space?

NOTE:
It's "img_strip" that is supposed to auto expand, not "container".

```css
            .container {
                width: 320px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
    
            img {
                height: 20px;
            }
    
            .strip_container {
                position: relative;
                height: 25px;
            }
    
            .img_strip {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                margin: 1px;
                /*
                 * It's displayed on one line if I specify
                 * an exact width 
                 *
                 * width: 200px;
                 */
    
            }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="strip_container">
            <div class="img_strip">
                <a href="#"><img src="src/main/resources/static/images/com_phone.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="src/main/resources/static/images/com_email.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="src/main/resources/static/images/com_url.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="src/main/resources/static/images/com_address1.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="src/main/resources/static/images/com_facebook.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="src/main/resources/static/images/com_facebook.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="src/main/resources/static/images/com_facebook.png"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give left 50% and trasnfrom -50% so its occupy 50% of your width so give `text-align:center` with `left:0px;` `right:0px;` and it will occupy full width of div

```css
.container {
                width: 320px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
    
            img {
                height: 20px;
            }
    
            .strip_container {
                position: relative;
                height: 25px;
            }
    
            .img_strip {
                right: 0;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translate(0%, -50%);
                margin: 1px;
                text-align: center;
                /*
                 * It's displayed on one line if I specify
                 * an exact width 
                 *
                 * width: 200px;
                 */
    
            }
            
            img{
            width:15px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="strip_container">
            <div class="img_strip">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually You used position: absolute; left: 50%; So left 50% contain half space... make proper CSS for it.. i think you don't need to use position:absolute; use display : block and align center

Answer (score 1):

```css
            .common_container {
                width: auto;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
    
            img {
                height: 20px;
            }
    
            .strip_container {
                position: relative;
                height: 25px;
            }
    
            .img_strip {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                margin: 1px;
                /*
                 * It's displayed on one line if I specify
                 * an exact width 
                 *
                 * width: 200px;
                 */
    
            }
```

```html
<div class="common_container">
        <div class="strip_container">
            <div class="img_strip">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/phone.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/phone.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/phone.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/phone.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/phone.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/phone.png"/></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/phone.png"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the outside container needs to have a fixed size

Comment: @rune Try with the one `.img_strip {
                position: relative;
                left: 235px;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                margin: 1px;
                /*
                 * It's displayed on one line if I specify
                 * an exact width 
                 *
                 * width: 200px;
                 */
    
            }`

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
                width: 320px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
```

width: 320px sets the width as is. You can change this to min-width so that it will still expand.

Comment: it seems like you think that it's the outside container that's supposed to expand, but it is img_strip that is supposed to expand.